# Why does my Linq query throw an exception when I try and sort on DateTime?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this method that is meant to filter my blog entries by month...

```
public IList<KeyValuePair<string, int>> GetBlogsByMonth(PteDotNetCore.EnumsAndConstants.BlogType blogTypeArg)
        {
            var blogsOfType = from b in dataContext.blogs
                               where b.BlogType == (int)blogTypeArg
                               select b;


            IList<KeyValuePair<string, int>> retVal = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

            for(int i= 12; i > 1; i--)
            {
                var blogsInMonth = from b in blogsOfType
                                   where ((DateTime)b.DateAdded).Month == DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-i).Month
                                   select b;

                KeyValuePair<string, int> keyToAdd = new KeyValuePair<string, int>(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-i).Month.ToString(), blogsInMonth.ToList().Count);

                retVal.Add(keyToAdd);

            }

            return retVal;

        }
```

When I use the debugger **blogsInMonth**  I get an error

```
base {System.SystemException} = {"Nullable object must have a value."}
```

Blog is an entity framework object. To be honest Im a bit confused as to why I have to look in the Value of the blog.DateTime object. Even when I change it to...

```
var blogsInMonth = from b in blogsOfType
                                   where ((DateTime)b.DateAdded).Month == DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-i).Month
                                   select b;
```

It still doesnt work...Hope someone can help...

Comment: Is `DateAdded` a `DateTime?` (`Nullable<DateTime>`)?  If so, then that indicates that one of the `DateAdded` objects is null rather than holding a value and you should check for null first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the `Blog.DateAdded` column is nullable in the database and there exists null values in the column.

You can try

```
where b.DateAdded != null && ((DateTime)b.DateAdded).Month == DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-i).Month
```

Comment: okay this works, however I dont have any null values in my data though?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because your `b.DateAdded` is null. Try changing the lines at the top as follows:

```
var blogsOfType = from b in dataContext.blogs
    where b.DateAdded != null && b.BlogType == (int)blogTypeArg
    select b;
```

As a matter of optimization, you can calculate "i moths back" outside of your Linq expression. In case there are many blog entries, you wouldn't be doing `DateTime.Now.AddMonth(-1)` more times than necessary.